# Как спарсить страницу, для доступа к которой нужен логин и пароль?

Tags: php, парсер, авторизация, синтаксический-анализ

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как автоматически авторизоваться на сайте при помощи php. Какие есть методы. Мне посоветовали использовать объект-браузер, а затем обращаться к нему при помощи this-> , но не смог найти информацию об этом

Comment: Убил коммент... С пятого раза только понял о чем суть) вот [видео][1] может помочь


  [1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=9tG4OMQNFWc#!

Comment: Да, в принципе следовать этому совету необязательно. Просто нужно направление куда, вообще, копать.

Comment: Не, как раз вся суть в том, чтобы не самому вбивать данные в форму авторизации,а предоставить это php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да это легко делается. Сначала через дебаггер смотрится, какие запросы посылаются серверу и какие приходят. Дальше по этим данным составляем запрос с помощью `curl`, т.к. он идеально подходит для таких случаев (а вдруг и куки нужны?).

Comment: Да, присоединяюсь к @lampa. Не раз так делал сам.

Answer (score 0):

Я советую Perl, он удобнее для парсинга.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$browser->agent('Mozilla/8.0 [ru] (Win98; U)');
my $url     = "http://www.site.ru";
my $response = $browser->get($url);
#Получим корень сайта
my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($response->decoded_content);
#а так ищем элемент странички
$root->look_down('_tag'  => 'div',
class' => "big");
```

Это чтобы взять страничку, а чтобы отправить - нужно отправить данные на сервер по другому и получить ответ. Можно и на PHP, но Perl подходит больше для парсинга и для управлении с консоли.

Comment: У человека в теге php указан. Видимо, любой здравомыслящий не будет пересаживаться на другой ЯП из-за того, что перл почему-то лучше подходит :-)